# ¿Cómo debo conjugar el verbo en este caso?

Tags: conjugación

Cuál de las siguientes oraciones es gramaticalmente correcta:

(1) Me gusta la mayoría de los autores rusos.
(2) Me gusta***n*** la mayoría de los autores rusos.

Gracias!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ambas formas son correctas, aunque la más habitual es la (2), con el verbo en plural.

(Puedes revisar el punto [4.9 de la entrada para Concordancia del Diccionario Panhispánico de Dudas](https://www.rae.es/dpd/concordancia), donde se aclara este tema de la concordancia en sintagmas con "mayoría", "resto" y "mitad". No es un tema breve, hay casos y reglas, pero para ayudarte baste con lo dicho más arriba).